# Media Streaming Option Missing on Windows 11 Home

Tags: windows-11, dlna

I'm not able to enable the built-in DLNA server on Windows. I have tried many methods given online and everything [suggested on this website](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-dlna-media-streaming-in-windows-10-and-windows-11.10295/):

1. Reinstall Windows 11;
2. `gpedit.msc`: In Group Policy editor, there was no option as "Window Media Player" (I had enabled `gpedit` through a [hack](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/add_gpedit_msc_with_powershell.html));
3. Windows Media Player settings: There is no such option;
4. Windows features: Doesn't have the option of Windows Media Player;
5. Network and Sharing center —> looks like this! [image]

and yes windows media player is installed
[image]

Comment: Have you installed Windows Media Player from the Microsoft store?

Comment: It is preinstalled. and yes, even in Microsoft Store, it says installed

Comment: AFAIK, this has to be configured first: _Change advanced sharing settings_

Comment: there is no media sharing options there, it just has private network (network discovery, file and printer sharing) both are enabled

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you AREN'T on some "N" Windows version? Any Windows N needs installation of an additional pack, apparently. Or, better, upgrade to a normal, non-N, version.

Comment: iI says , version 23h2, and os name as Microsoft windows 11 home single language .

Comment: That's the build number not the version.

Comment: how do I check if its the n version? i checked this via running winver. and there was no mention N anywhere on the screen. plus i don't live in European region

Comment: Then it isn't "N" and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: please help figure it out or suggest alternative. dlna server, which runs exclusively locally

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by installing the legacy windows media player in windows optional features its not enough to just install media features. You will find this option by searching optional features > More windows features > Click + by media features > Select Windows Media Player Legacy (App) then press ok to install.